# How to expose Qt built-in enums to QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm writing a C++ class with a method which returns `QNetworkReply::NetworkError`. I would like to use this enum inside QML and not only treat it as an integer, so that I can do:

```
if (myObject.error() == NetworkError.OperationCanceledError) {
```

instead of

```
if (myObject.error() == 5) {
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need to do is:

in main:

```
qmlRegisterUncreatableType<QNetworkReply>("someimport", 1, 0, "QNetworkReply", "none");
```

then in qml:

```
import someimport 1.0
...
if (myObject.error() == QNetworkReply.OperationCanceledError) {
```

QNetworkReply already contains Q_ENUM and Q_DECLARE_METATYPE macros, so what is left is to export it to QML

Answer (score 2):

In general you just need to use the [Q_ENUM](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_ENUM) macro to expose enums to QML, but I think you also need to register the related class type with [qmlRegisterType](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterType).

So if you do something like

```
Q_ENUM(NetworkError) // in myclass.h
qmlRegisterType<App>("com.myapp.classes", 1, 0, "MyClass"); // in myclass.cpp
```

you should be able to access the enums in QML with:

```
import com.myapp.classes 1.0
if (myObject.error() == MyClass.OperationCanceledError) { ... }
```

Comment: I'm struggling with the `Q_ENUM(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)` part. When I try to compile it, I get: `function 'const QMetaObject *qt_getEnumMetaObject(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)' already has a body` which makes sense seeing that the `Q_ENUM` macro is used inside Qt's library already.